# Catching the last (final) url after all redirects

Tags: c#, redirect, httpclient, vk, asp.net-core-2.0

ASP.NET Core 2.0
I have a problem with catching the final url after all redirects. **There are a redirect using js** as shows photo below, so HttpClient contains only first page url as RequestUri. It's also true for HttpWebRequest and SimpleBrowser.
[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvoF0.png)
I need to get `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=bee0e251e716bd3ece938db0ab47c2bf530ccc856710c51d357b4ec0d3da2865a3a0fd93f7393a177c14c&expires_in=86400&user_id=301771062`
*Token is expired, don't try to use it*

**UPDATE** ResponseUri and RequestUri are the same

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the HttpWebResponse.ResponseUri

Possibly related:
[How to get redirected url as string after request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317204/how-to-get-redirected-url-as-string-after-request)

Comment: I tried ResponseUri, as I wrote there was the first url `https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6055184&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=friends,wall,photos,messages&response_type=token&v=5.68`

Comment: Ok, then you might want to edit your question, because it says that you found that original value in the RequestUri, whereas I was suggesting that you look at the ResponseUri returned in the HttpWebResponse.

Comment: it also contains url as I said above. Request url and response url are the same